# Validation fails for mutually exclusive checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I have two checkboxes. The validation condition is on form-submit, the form should be valid if and only if one checkbox is checked.

Went about doing like this. Gave the two checkboxes same classname and on ng-click I looped through the checkboxes and found the checked count like this.

```
$scope.SetCheckDatesCount = function () {
    $scope.CheckedDatesCount = 0;
    var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("AcceptedChecks");
    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            $scope.CheckedDatesCount++;
        }
    }
};
```

Now in markup I set,

```
ng-required="CheckedDatesCount != 1"
```

So, that the checkbox will be ng-required when `CheckedDatesCount = 0 ||CheckedDatesCount = 2`.

But the validation won't work if I check two checkboxes.

Plunkr Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/ekGCpdXspQAf6zTwDToT?p=preview

I could stop form submit by using an extra check like this. (But is that very clean?)

```
if (theForm.$invalid && CheckedDatesCount != 1) {
    $scope.showMessages = true;
    return;
}
```

Why is the form *not invalid* when two checkboxes are checked.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not radio buttons?

Comment: @developer033: that was the design I have been given. I am more curious to know why my code doesn't work. logic semed correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to check the state of the checkobox. i think you could do this-

```
      <div class="row">
        <button ng-disabled="!((Interview.InterviewAccepted || Interview.AlternateAccepted) && (Interview.InterviewAccepted != Interview.AlternateAccepted) )" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AcceptInterview(DemoForm)">
          Accept
        </button>
      </div>
```

OR you could do this:-

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="DemoController">

        <div class="container" ng-form="DemoForm">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>Is Interview Date Accepted: </label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="AcceptedChecks" name="InterviewAccepted" ng-model="Interview.InterviewAccepted" ng-required="1 && !Interview.AlternateAccepted" ng-click="SetCheckDatesCount()" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label>Is Alternate Date Accepted: </label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="AcceptedChecks" name="AlternateAccepted" ng-model="Interview.AlternateAccepted" ng-required="1 && ! Interview.InterviewAccepted" ng-click="SetCheckDatesCount()" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="AcceptInterview(DemoForm)">
              Accept
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>

    </html>
    <script>
    // Code goes here
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("DemoController", ["$scope", function($scope){
      $scope.showMessages = false;
      $scope.Interview = {
        AlternateAccepted: false,
        InterviewAccepted: false
      };


      $scope.AcceptInterview = function (theForm) {
        console.log(theForm.$invalid);
        if (theForm.$invalid) {
            $scope.showMessages = true;
            return;
        }
        alert("valid");
      }
    }]);

    </script>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand why `ng-required=true` state is not toggled properly.

Comment: the second method is much better than mine. thanks. but it still fails. take a look. https://plnkr.co/edit/99ippas0GIgUgVHhhJ3l?p=preview. Its the select two checkbox validation that fails.

Comment: @naveen do you only want to use ng-required or you will be ok with ng-disabled?

Comment: dont understand why ng-required doesn't work. No offense to your answer. +1 :)